# no source file of a neural network model

Tags: python, pytorch

if I only have a '.pth' file of a neural network(without source code of it), is there any way to get the structure of this network? For example, i saved a resnet model by

```
model = ResNet()
torch.save(model, 'model.pth')
```

then i deleted or moved the source code of 'ResNet', how can I get the structure by 'model.pth'
please forgive my poor English if I didn't express clearly .T T

only want to talk about this quesetion, maybe there is no method to solve it :(

Comment: if I use 'torch.load('model.pth')' , the interpreter will give an ModuleNotFound error

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't get architecture of the model.

According to [pytorch docs](https://pytorch.org/tutorials/beginner/saving_loading_models.html#save-load-entire-model)

> Saving a model in this way will save the entire module using Python’s pickle module. The disadvantage of this approach is that the serialized data is bound to the specific classes and the exact directory structure used when the model is saved. The reason for this is because pickle does not save the model class itself. Rather, it saves a path to the file containing the class, which is used during load time.

Answer (score 0):

Since you want to view the structure you can use below code

```
import torch

# Specify the path to your .pth file
file_path = './model_new.pth'

# Load the checkpoint to inspect its structure
checkpoint = torch.load(file_path, map_location=torch.device('cpu'))

# Print the keys in the checkpoint dictionary
print("Keys in the checkpoint:", checkpoint.keys())

# Print the details of each layer
for key, value in checkpoint.items():
    print(f"\nKey: {key}")
    print(f"Value Type: {type(value)}")
    if isinstance(value, torch.Tensor):
        print(f"Shape: {value.shape}")
        print(f"Values:\n{value}")
```

Hope this helps!